# What is the expectation of switch activation?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Consider $n$ switches, which activate at rate $a_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$. The time it takes for a specific switch to activate, $T_i$, satisfies $T_i\sim \text{Exp}(a_i)$. In particular, $E[T_i]=1/a_i$.

Now, imagine there are $m$ activating factors (available at any time for the $n$ switches) so that each switch only activates once it is bound to exactly $1$ activating factor (say, at a rate $b$). Once a switch is activated, the activating factor is recycled at rate $r$.

For example, if $b$ is high and $r$ is low, we expect early activation of $m$ switches (if $m<n$), followed by a period of no activation.

What distribution does $T_i$ now follows? Is it possible to work out its expectation?

**Edit:** Following a comment, I would just add that both binding and recycling times are exponentially distributed with the given rates, and the switch an activating factor binds to is chosen uniformly at random among those not yet activated.

Comment: Presumably, binding and recycling times are exponentially distributed with the given rates, and the switch an activating factor binds to is chosen uniformly at random among those not yet activated?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, that is correct. I will add that to the question.

Comment: The distribution of $T_i$ will be non-standard in general, but you can find its expectation by treating the problem as a continuous-time Markov chain, and solving the hitting-time equations.

Comment: @Adam could you elaborate on this?